AWS Cognito customized attributes are disappearing
I'm using Amazon Cognito as our authentication service in a Spring Boot application. I initially configured my user pool with custom attributes, and everything seemed fine. However, these custom attributes keep disappearing unexpectedly.
I'm not sure why this happens, as it doesn’t follow any specific pattern. It doesn’t seem to be triggered by API requests or token expiration either. I can manually add the custom attribute to a user profile, save it, and it works temporarily, but then at some point, it just disappears without any apparent reason.
I've searched online for solutions but haven’t found any answers. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?
Also I already tried to read the entire documentation and found nothing

I had a similar issue and realized I made a mistake while testing Identity Provider Attribute Mapping.
In the Attribute Mapping, I had something like "preferred_username: surname", but I also used the Lambda Triggers to set this same attribute "preferred_username" when the user first signed up.
The "surname" value from the Identity Provider came empty, and each time a user authenticates through IdP, its attributes are refreshed, so each time a user authenticated in my app, its "preferred_username" was erased because of the empty value of the "surname" from IdP.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-specifying-attribute-mapping.html
Seventh paragraph:
When a user signs in through an IdP, Amazon Cognito updates the mapped attributes with the latest information from the IdP. Amazon Cognito updates each mapped attribute, even if its current value already matches the latest information. 
Hope that helps,
